# Change locale in data base android development

Tags: java, android, database, locale, multilingual

How can I localize the database for the project in other languages ​​(for example en, ru, fr and others)

I have an already ready database in English, but I want to make the application multilingual and able to work with other databases depending on the device locale.

I've already seen a lot of forums on this issue, but in each of them it says that you need to get the current locale. But I can not understand where these codes should be attributed. My code is completely listed below.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper
{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = MuseumConfig.DATABASE_NAME;
    private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/" + CookbookApplication.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = CookbookConfig.DATABASE_VERSION;
    private static final String PREFS_KEY_DATABASE_VERSION = "database_version";

    private Dao<CategoryModel, Long> mCategoryDao = null;
    private Dao<AboutModel, Long> mRecipeDao = null;
    private Dao<InformationModel, Long> mIngredientDao = null;


    // singleton
    private static DatabaseHelper instance;
    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance()
    {
        if(instance==null) instance = new DatabaseHelper();
        return instance;
    }


    private DatabaseHelper()
    {
        super(CookbookApplication.getContext(), DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        if(!databaseExists() || DATABASE_VERSION>getVersion())
        {
            synchronized(this)
            {
                boolean success = copyPrepopulatedDatabase();
                if(success)
                {
                    setVersion(DATABASE_VERSION);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource)
    {
        try
        {
            Logcat.d("DatabaseHelper.onCreate()");
            //TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, CategoryModel.class);
            //TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, RecipeModel.class);
            //TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, IngredientModel.class);
        }
        catch(android.database.SQLException e)
        {
            Logcat.e("DatabaseHelper.onCreate(): can't create database", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        try
        {
            Logcat.d("DatabaseHelper.onUpgrade()");
        }
        catch(android.database.SQLException e)
        {
            Logcat.e("DatabaseHelper.onUpgrade(): can't upgrade database", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void close()
    {
        super.close();
        mCategoryDao = null;
        mRecipeDao = null;
        mIngredientDao = null;
    }


    public synchronized void clearDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            Logcat.d("DatabaseHelper.clearDatabase()");

            TableUtils.dropTable(getConnectionSource(), CategoryModel.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(getConnectionSource(), RecipeModel.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(getConnectionSource(), IngredientModel.class, true);

            TableUtils.createTable(getConnectionSource(), CategoryModel.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(getConnectionSource(), RecipeModel.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(getConnectionSource(), IngredientModel.class);
        }
        catch(android.database.SQLException e)
        {
            Logcat.e("DatabaseHelper.clearDatabase(): can't clear database", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(java.sql.SQLException e)
        {
            Logcat.e("DatabaseHelper.clearDatabase(): can't clear database", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public synchronized Dao<CategoryModel, Long> getCategoryDao() throws java.sql.SQLException
    {
        if(mCategoryDao==null)
        {
            mCategoryDao = getDao(CategoryModel.class);
        }
        return mCategoryDao;
    }


    public synchronized Dao<RecipeModel, Long> getRecipeDao() throws java.sql.SQLException
    {
        if(mRecipeDao==null)
        {
            mRecipeDao = getDao(RecipeModel.class);
        }
        return mRecipeDao;
    }


    public synchronized Dao<IngredientModel, Long> getIngredientDao() throws java.sql.SQLException
    {
        if(mIngredientDao==null)
        {
            mIngredientDao = getDao(IngredientModel.class);
        }
        return mIngredientDao;
    }


    private boolean databaseExists()
    {
        File file = new File(DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
        boolean exists = file.exists();
        Logcat.d("DatabaseHelper.databaseExists(): " + exists);
        return exists;
    }


    private boolean copyPrepopulatedDatabase()
    {
        String locale = java.util.Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName();


        // copy database from assets
        try
        {
            // create directories
            File dir = new File(DATABASE_PATH);
            dir.mkdirs();

            // output file name
            String outputFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            Logcat.d("DatabaseHelper.copyDatabase(): " + outputFileName);

            // create streams
            InputStream inputStream = CookbookApplication.getContext().getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

            // write input to output
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while((length = inputStream.read(buffer))>0)
            {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // close streams
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            return true;
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }


    private int getVersion()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CookbookApplication.getContext());
        return sharedPreferences.getInt(PREFS_KEY_DATABASE_VERSION, 0);
    }


    private void setVersion(int version)
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CookbookApplication.getContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(PREFS_KEY_DATABASE_VERSION, version);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid the code you posted doesn't really help. There are many ways to implement multiple languages. I don't think anyone can give you a reasonable suggestion of how to do it in your project without knowing what you're going to do.

Comment: This feels a bit too broad for SO. The answer is really "it depends" because we don't know your requirements or limitations. In general the DB may not be the best place for localization, but it depends on the tech used in your application, and where you want to make the decision about localization (client app, web app, etc.) It's complicated and unlikely to be answerable in a single SO answer.